# Exporting/Serializing configurable Fields

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I need to serialize properties(HTTP POST to another service) based on the configuration set by the user in app.config.
Whats the best way to achieve this in C#.

Example

```
public Class Student { 

public string Name {get; set;}
public string Grade { get, set}
public string Address {get; set}
```

}

User can configure the settings file. for ex:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ExportName" value="true"/>
 <add key="ExportGrade" value="true"/>
 <add key="ExportAddress" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

In this case i donot want to serialize/export address. Is there a way i can use JsonIgnore or something similar ?

Comment: One way to do that is by writing a custom converter. Within the custom converter, fetch your configuration data and perform the required serialization at runtime.

Comment: it would be good if you can post sample code or point to some link

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your export configuration as follows:

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="Student.Name.Export" value="true"/>
     <add key="Student.Grade.Export" value="true"/>
     <add key="Student.Address.Export" value="false"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Then load the configuration as a `Dictionary<String, Boolean>` (keep in mind by using a dictionary here you will only use its data structure and you can by no means benefit from its lookup table performance).

At this point, you can automate your serialization process:

```
public static String SerializeObject<T>(T obj, Dictionary<String, Boolean> conf)
{
    Type typeofT = typeof(T);
    Regex exp = new Regex($"{typeofT}.*.Export");
    IEnumerable<(String Key, Boolean Value)> peropertyConfigurations =
        from pair in conf
        where exp.IsMatch(pair.Key) && pair.Value == true
        select (pair.Key, pair.Value);

    // CAUTION: This does not work if your property is a reference to another Model/Type
    // In that case you have to loop through the nested type as well.
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> queryProperties = 
        from property in typeofT.GetProperties()
        join propertyConfiguration in peropertyConfigurations
        on property.Name equals propertyConfiguration.Key
        select property;
    T filteredObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    foreach(var property in queryProperties){
        property.SetValue(filteredObject, property.GetValue(obj));
    }
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(filteredObject);
}
```